# How to set style for map item in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to `reactjs`. I have an `array` that will be

```
const mediumNames = ["TAMIL Medium", "ENGLISH MEDIUM"]
```

I have generated two cards using this code:

```
const [selectedMediumColor, setSelectedMediumColor] = useState('')

<div>
    {mediumNames.map((text, index,) => (

    <Card style={{ border: selectedMediumColor }} onClick={() => onClickMedium(text,index)} >
        <div >
            <img className={classes.imginCardBoard} src={TNlogo}></img>
                <Typography className={classes.textinCardBoard} > { text} </Typography>
        </div>
    </Card>
    ))}
</div>
```

I want to set Border Color when clicking Cards in ReactJS.  If the user selects the first card, the border color should be blue and the next card border color should be white and vice versa.

Here's the Function Code I wrote:

```
 const onClickMedium = (medium,indexno) => {
        console.log(medium)
        console.log(indexno)

        if (medium === "TAMIL Medium") {
            
            selectedMediumColor('2px solid #00adb5')
        }
        else {
            selectedMediumColor('')

        }
    }
```

it is setting the color for both cards. Here's the Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Ks2.jpg)

I want the color to be set for one card only. How can I achieve this? Please Help me with some solutions.

Comment: You need to do something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012531/%ef%bc%a8ow-to-use-menu-or-popover-on-mapping-components-in-react/69012662#69012662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach where you can set the selected index:

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState('')

 <div>
    {mediumNames.map((text, index,) => (

    <Card style={{ border: index === selectedIndex ? '2px solid #00adb5' : 'none'}} onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)} >
        <div >
            <img className={classes.imginCardBoard} src={TNlogo}></img>
                <Typography className={classes.textinCardBoard} > { text} </Typography>
        </div>
    </Card>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: The downside with this approach is if i have 100 cards ,and if i change the style of card - 1 all the 100 cards will re-render . An ideal solution for these scenarios is to move the card and the state to its own component . Since each card has its own state now selecting card 1 will re-render only card 1.

Answer (score 1):

As @Harshit's answer, it is an approach to achieve the result. But it could be extended as follows to handle more than 2 medium in your case as follows

```
export default function App() {
  const mediumNames = ["TAMIL Medium", "ENGLISH MEDIUM"];
  const mediumBorder = ["2px solid #00adb5", "2px solid red"];

  const [selectedMedium, setSelectedMedium] = useState("");
  const [selectedMediumIndex, setSelectedMediumIndex] = useState("");

  const onClickMedium = (medium, indexno) => {
    setSelectedMedium(medium);
    setSelectedMediumIndex(indexno);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        {mediumNames.map((text, index) => (
          <div
            style={{
              border:
                selectedMedium === text ? mediumBorder[selectedMediumIndex] : ""
            }}
            onClick={() => onClickMedium(text, index)}
          >
            <div>test</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this way you can handle any number of medium with custom border style for each medium.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-butterfly-w4r7m?file=/src/App.js:59-899)